# Does Ubuntu update the installation media?

Tags: installation, updates, live-cd, patch, stable-release-updates

When Ubuntu publishes a patch to packages, do they update the install media?

If I download a "live CD", will it be pre-patched?

What about SRU (stable release updates)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LiveCD images for an Ubuntu version which is still in beta/development get updated on a daily basis in its daily live images. For instance, you can get an up-to-date development version of upcoming Ubuntu 12.10 [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/).

**The LiveCD for a version is not update once it is released as final.** Then, updates are only pushed through the Update Manager.

For an LTS release, however, Canonical releases maintenance updates (like Windows Service Packs) periodically, which include patches released for the version. For instance, Ubuntu 10.04 is in its 4th maintenance update which can be downloaded [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/).

Comment: For what it's worth, I think they call them "maintenance updates" rather than "service packs." See the point-release announcements at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LucidLynx.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, updates aren't patched into the install CD, but from 12.04 installers have the ability to download updates during installation from a mirror.

Comment: Which of course is great when the patch is needed to get the wireless internet working :-)

Comment: I see your problem :/

Comment: @gecko, do you need the package with your wireless drivers, or a patched version of some package? jackweirdy, I think the installer has had the option to update during installation for awhile now, not just starting with 12.04.

Comment: @zpletan: I needed a LAN cable. That's sorted now :-)  And yes, downloading during installation is not new to Precise.